# Выигрыш в памяти и производительности между использованием числовой константы и численного значения?

Tags: c#

Чем отличается расход памяти и процессорного времени при использовании цифры 1 повсюду в коде от расхода при использовании на её местах константы, приведённой ниже?

```
public const byte ONE = 1;
```

Comment: Ничем не отличается

Comment: Константы удобны человеку - не нужно искать их по всему коду чтобы поменять и у них есть названия, а с точки зрения компилятора разницы нет.

Comment: Мне кажется, производительность надо в других местах искать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ничем. Понятие константа существует лишь на уровне языка. На уровне MSIL загрузка числа и загрузка константы - это одна и та же инструкция.

```cs
public class C {
    public const byte ONE = 1;
    public int M() {
        int result = 1;
        result += ONE;
        return result;
    }
}
```

```
IL_0000: ldc.i4.1
IL_0001: ldc.i4.1
IL_0002: add
```

Answer (score 3):

Небольшая разница между константой и литералом в данном случае всё же есть.

Литерал `1` будет иметь тип `Int32`. Константа имеет тип `Byte`.

Компилятор примет в расчёт типы при вызове перегрузок метода, если таковые имеются.

```
using var stream = new MemoryStream();
using var writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);
                
writer.Write(1); // перегрузка, принимающая int
writer.Write(Some.ONE); // перегрузка, принимающая byte

Console.WriteLine(stream.Length); // 5
```